# GoogleMap: center or defaultCenter property must be defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My project is using the GoogleMapReact component and when I start the application my map doesn't load and I receive the following warnings:

GoogleMap: center or defaultCenter property must be defined

Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader. This may result in undesirable behavior as options and script parameters may not match.

I dont know if this is an issue within the GoogleMapReactComponent or the Map component in app.js so I will post both if anyone can help me break down why the map isn't loading it would be a big help. Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { Paper, Typography, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';
import LocationOnOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOnOutlined';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';

import useStyles from './styles';

import mapStyles from './mapStyles'


const Map = ({coords, setCoords, setBounds, places, setChildClicked, weatherData}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');


    return (
        <div
       className={classes.mapContainer}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
                defaultCenter={coords}
                center={coords}
                defaultZoom={14}
                margin={[50, 50, 50, 50,]}
                options={{ disableDefaultUI: true, zoomControl: true, styles: mapStyles }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setCoords({ lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng });
                    setBounds({ ne: e.marginBounds.ne, sw: e.marginBounds.sw });
                }}

                onChildClick={(child) => setChildClicked(child)}

            >
                {places?.length && places?.map((place, i) => (
                    <div
                        className={classes.markerContainer}
                        lat={Number(place.latitude)}
                        lng={Number(place.longitude)}
                        key={i}
                    >

                        {!matches ?
                            <LocationOnOutlinedIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />
                            : (
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom> {place.name}</Typography>
                                    <img
                                        className={classes.pointer}
                                        src={place.photo ? place.photo.images.large.url : 'https://www.rlare.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Inside-1-1.jpg'}
                                        alt={place.name}
                                    />
                                    <Rating size="small" value={Number(place.rating)} name="read-only" />

                                </Paper>
                            )}

                    </div>
                ))}

                {weatherData?.list?.length && weatherData.list.map((data, i) => (
                    <div key={i} lat={data.coord.lat} lng={data.coord.lon}>
                        <img src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`} height="70px" alt="map"/>

                    </div>
                ))}

            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CssBaseline, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import { getPlacesData, getWeatherData } from './api/index'
 
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import List from './components/List/List';
import Map from './components/Map/Map';



const App = () => {
    const [type, setType] = useState('restaurants');
    const [rating, setRating] = useState('');
  
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);
  
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
    const [filteredPlaces, setFilteredPlaces] = useState([]);
    const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
  
    const [autocomplete, setAutocomplete] = useState(null);
    const [childClicked, setChildClicked] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: {latitude, longitude} }) => {
            setCoords({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude});

        });

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const filtered = places.filter((place) => Number(place.rating) > rating);

        setFilteredPlaces(filtered);
    }, [rating]);
     
    useEffect(() => {
        if(bounds) {
        setIsLoading(true);

        getWeatherData(coords.lat, coords.lng)
        .then((data) => setWeatherData(data));

        getPlacesData(type, bounds.sw, bounds.ne)
        .then((data) => {
            setPlaces(data.filter((place) => place.name && place.num_reviews > 0));
            setFilteredPlaces([]);
            setRating('');
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }

    },[bounds, type]);

    const onLoad = (autoC) => setAutocomplete(autoC);
    
    const onPlaceChanged = () => {
        const lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
        const lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();

        setCoords({ lat, lng });
    };


    return (
     <>
     <CssBaseline />
     <Header onPlaceChanged={onPlaceChanged} onLoad={onLoad} />
     <Grid container spacing ={3} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
         <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
             <List 
             places={filteredPlaces.length ? filteredPlaces : places}
             childClicked={childClicked}
             isLoading={isLoading}
             type={type}
             setType={setType}
             setRating={setRating}
             rating={rating}
             
             />

         </Grid>
         <Grid item xs={12} md={8} style={{display: 'flex', justfiyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
             <Map 
             setChildClicked={setChildClicked}
             setCoordinates={setCoords}
             setBounds={setBounds}
             coordinates={coords}
             places={filteredPlaces?.length ? filteredPlaces : places}
             weatherData={weatherData}
             />
             
         </Grid>

     </Grid>

     
     </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is `coords` and where is it coming from?

Comment: I declared it in the map.jsx file and also used it in the app.js file. Let me edit the post and put the whole files for context

Answer (score 0):

On the initial mount of your components, `coords` is just an empty object.  The `useEffect` that populates it doesn't run until after the first render.  A typical pattern to deal with this is to render nothing or a loading component when the required props are not available.  The simplest route would be to set the initial state of `coords` to something falsey and only render `Map` when it isn't falsey

```
const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});
...
{coords && <Map ... />}
```

Another option would be to keep track of whether `coords` has been loaded within state -

```
const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});
const [coordsLoaded, setCoordsLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: {latitude, longitude} }) => {
        setCoords({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude});
        setCoordsLoaded(true);
    });
}, []);

...
{coordsLoaded && <Map ... />}
```

Comment: Hey Larz! Thank you for your response. This has been bothering me for several days now. Where should I put {coords && <Map ... />} ? I'm a little confused my apoligies.

Comment: Inside the `Grid` where you're currently rendering your `Map` component.  That little piece of code says "If coords aren't available, don't render anything.  If they are, go ahead and render the Map`.

Comment: Okay I'm slowly understanding what you're saying thank you so much I am just having a hard time understanding the <Map .../> part because when I input this I get an error. line 88:29:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (88:29)

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't copy your entire Map component with its props for readability's sake.  You'll want to continue to pass the props as you previously were.

Comment: I see what you mean now however after trying both of your solutions I am still receiving the same error codes . Do you have any idea as to why that might be?

Comment: Can you verify that `coords` is getting properly set after your `useEffect` is called?

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question but how do I check if coords is properly set? Would that refer to  useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: {latitude, longitude} }) => {
            setCoords({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude});?

Comment: I would toss a `console.log(coords)` inside the body of your `App` component.  Ideally it should be an empty object/null (depending on which of the above solutions you are using) and then on a subsequent render, should be correctly populated.  If it isn't, there may be a problem with how you're getting them.  I think that would return `undefined` or something if a user declines to share their location.

Comment: After inputing console.log(coords) I receive a random set of coordinates in the console